# Issue in sending html file as attachment

Tags: python, mailer

I am trying to send email with either .pdf or .html file as attachment using python.
Following code works fine if i send pdf file, but if I attach html file then I get the exception.

```
def send_mail(app, sub, body, filename=None):

    FROM = Config.Email.FROM_ADDRESS
    TO = Config.Email.FAIL_RECIPIENTS
    sender = Mailer(Config.Email.SMTP_SERVER)

    message = Message(From = FROM, To = TO)
    message.Subject = sub
    message.Html = body
    if filename is not None:
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            message.Subject = sub + " " + '[Attachment is missing as the file path in invalid.]'
            sender.send(message)
            return
        else:
            message.attach(filename)
            try:
                sender.send(message)
                return
            except AttributeError:
                ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
            maintype, subtype = ctype.split('/', 1)
                if maintype == 'text':
                    fp = open(filename)
                    attach = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
                    fp.close()
                    attach.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
                    message.attach(filename)
                    sender.send(message)
                    return

        sender.send(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_mail()
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/git_workspace/proj/core/common_utils.py", line 65, in send_mail
sender.send(message)
  File "C:\Python_VEnv\automation\lib\site-packages\mailer.py", line 124, in send
    self._send(server, m)
  File "C:\Python_VEnv\automation\lib\site-packages\mailer.py", line 161, in _send
    server.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
  File "C:\Python_VEnv\automation\lib\site-packages\mailer.py", line 244, in as_string
    return self._multipart()
  File "C:\Python_VEnv\automation\lib\site-packages\mailer.py", line 349, in _multipart
    self._add_attachment(msg, filename, cid, mimetype, content, charset)
  File "C:\Python_VEnv\automation\lib\site-packages\mailer.py", line 375, in _add_attachment
    msg = MIMEText(content, _subtype=subtype, _charset=charset)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\email\mime\text.py", line 34, in __init__
_text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

What am i missing here?